# Style guide for asymptotic notation

Tags: reference-request, notation, asymptotics, relations, symmetry

There are two widely accepted forms of asymptotic notation:

1. $f(n) = O(g(n))$
2. $f(n) ∈ O(g(n))$

1 seems to be more widely used, but implies a symmetry between the two sides that just isn't there. 2 is less confusing in that way, but is less used.

Are there any commonly used mathematical style guides that recommend one over the other? Or at least ones that say something on the matter?

Comment: Thanks—done! :)

Comment: 2. is a better notation, but 1. is almost always used. @TinMan

Comment: Lots of common and widely-used notation and terminology could be improved.  But changing it for that reason is almost never successful.

Comment: For example, $f(n)$ appearing there is not a number (as it seems to be) but abusive notation for a function $n \mapsto f(n)$.  Perhaps someone should propose notation $(n \mapsto f(n)) \in O(n \mapsto g(n))$.  No, please don't.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know. I'd be interested to know if there is a style guide that could back up that argument. I'd like to set a standard in a group, and arguments like "I like this better" don't hold much water.

Comment: @TinMan There are no accepted "style guides" in maths.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What about the AMS Style Guide?

Comment: Or the Mathematics section in Wikipedia's Manual of Style: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Manual_of_Style/Mathematics ?

Comment: Both of those are guides for *typesetting*, not for notation.

Comment: @AntonioVargas There's a "Mathematical conventions" section on the Wikipedia page, with "Notational conventions" as a subsection.

Comment: Ah, you linked the talk page before so I didn't see it. That page may be a guide for writing math *on wikipedia*, but it's not a style guide for writing mathematics in general. I echo @LordSharktheUnknown 's comment that there are no **accepted** style guides in math.

Answer (score 4):

> There is no commonly used mathematical style guide that provides a recommendation. But sometimes one of the great tells us reasons for his preferences. An interesting paper of this kind is *[Big Omicron and Big Omega and Big Theta](http://www.phil.uu.nl/datastructuren/09-10/knuth_big_omicron.pdf)* by D.E. Knuth from 1976.

Comment: Just to quote what he says: "The equal sign here really means c (set inclusion), and this has bothered many people who propose that we not be allowed to use the = sign in this context. My feeling is that we should continue to use one-way equality together with O-notations~ since it has been common practice of thousands of mathematicians for so many years now, and since we understand the meaning of our existing notation sufficiently well."

Comment: @TinMan: I agree and I think that we can fully trust him, since he is not only a remarkable mathematician but also the man who gave us TeX. So, he *really* knows the things about good notation. :-)